# Is there a dynamic data structure that can be automatically serialized to XML or JSON?

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, jaxb

I'm developing a restful web-service that should be able to return `JSON` or `XML` responses upon request. Of course, the `JSON` response should be identical to the `XML` response when the data is compared.

The thing is that I can't use a Java pojo because the returned data fields are dynamic, they are unpredictable.

For example, a specific user may have the following response:

```
{
  "propertyA": "propertyA-Value",
  "propertyB": "propertyB-Value",
}
```

...another user may have:

```
{
  "propertyA": "propertyA-Value",
  "propertyB": "propertyB-Value",
  "propertyC": "propertyC-Value",
}
```

...or the XML representation would be

```
<results>
    <propertyA>propertyA-Value</propertyA>
    <propertyB>propertyB-Value</propertyB>
    <propertyC>propertyC-Value</propertyC>
</results>
```

Is there a way to **automatically** serialize the structure holding the previously mentioned data, to `JSON` or `XML`. By "automatically", I mean using an API that would work with whatever fields provided.

I can't use an array\list of feature-name\feature-value structures as the service consumer needs to receive the response as mentioned.

Comment: I don't understand. Seems like a `Map` should be enough.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thanks, but how will the `Map` be represented in `XML` and `JSON` ?

Comment: If the data is consistently passed as key-value pairs you should be able to use a `map`. To get that to `JSON`, you might take at `SimpleJson`, which has a constructor that takes a `map`.

Comment: @TheHeadRush, what about `XML` ? Will I have to construct is manually ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Sorry, i read "json or xml" as needing to convert to one or the other, not both. If you need to do both conversion, you might want JAXB. http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html

Answer (score 0):

use codehaus fasterxml object mapper. A sample app can be seen from below link

https://github.com/abhishek24509/JsonMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

the above code will help to hold dyamic response. Your pojo can have all possible field. But during mapping it will ignore unknown